# Sanitising a string in a *ngFor removes items that do not match

Tags: javascript, angular, string, replace

I have a simple *ngFor loop that displays a list of titles.

```
fetchData = [{"title":"woman%20.gif"},{"title":"aman",},{"title":"jessica",},{"title":"rosh"}];

<div *ngFor = "let title of fetchData">
  {{sanitiseIconString(title.title)}}
</div>
```

I run it through my sanitiser method to remove all `%20` references and anything and including `.extension` e.g. `.gif`, `.jpg`, `.png`

```
sanitiseIconString(str: string): string {
  return str && str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(".")).replace(/%20/g, " ");
}
```

My loop only returns `woman` which has been correctly sanitised but why are the others not displaying?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-2atjev?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: I realise its because the other titles do not have a "."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update sanitiseIconString in app.compoent.ts file

it is because your other title does not have **.** and **20%** so the condition is always false and not return

```
sanitiseIconString(str: string): string {
    return str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(".")).replace(/%20/g, " ")? str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(".")).replace(/%20/g, " "):str;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove %20 use `string.replace()`, it would be easier and simple

```
 <div *ngFor="let title of fetchData">
      {{title.title.replace('%20','')}}
      <!-- {{sanitiseIconString(title.title)}} -->
    </div>
```